# Python/Django and HTML/CSS/JS/jQuery on PostgreSQL/Apache?

Tags: python, html, apache, postgresql

I did the courses for HTML/CSS/JS/jQuery/Python on Codecademy and since then I've been practicing client side programming with HTML/CSS/JS/jQuery following documentation an tutorials using Notepad++ and Chrome.

I decided that it was time to start practicing server-side programming, so that I could integrate client side programming into a fully functional website. So, [I asked on Yahoo Answers](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index;_ylt=AlQUkydPP2ybi_IyvwYk0BmMJ3RG;_ylv=3?qid=20130105104227AA0oNJI) for the best way to practice server-side programming, and from the answers it seems that the best way is just to set up one of my old PCs as a server. The same guy also told me that PostgreSQL is not useable ('very few real servers will allow it'), that Apache is meant for PHP/MySQL, and that Python isn't used with HTML.

He said that I needed to relearn, so I am rather confused right now. I figured that Python/Ruby/PERL etc. were interchangeable with PHP, and were just different ways of doing the same thing? The same with PostgreSQL, it seemed to me that it was interchangeable with MySQL? I've not even used Python yet (aside from on Codecademy) as I haven't figured out how to use it, but I was really keen on using it for web development.

Comment: Let's just charitably say that person doesn't know what he's talking about it. I make my living from Python and the web, so what he's claiming is patently false.

Answer (score 2):

> from the answers it seems that the best way is just to set up one of my old PC's as a server

For the love of $DEITY, please do not do that. If you are just starting out, you do NOT want to have learn server management, installing various tools from the ground up (SSH, FTP, Apache, MySQL, etc), setting up router and static IP address, setting up firewall/iptables, setting up domain names, etc, etc, etc all at the same time. Learning all that at the same time will be too overwhelming.

I'd suggest using a [good shared hosting](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoFriendlyWebHosts) to reduce pain.

> PostgreSQL is not useable ('very few real servers will allow it'?); that Apache is meant for PHP/MySQL; and that Python isn't used with html

Whoever told you that is totally clueless. While PostgreSQL is less popular than MySQL, most of the serious web hosting supports it; Apache is one of the most flexible web servers, it supports a very wide range of web technologies, not just mod_php; and the claim that Python is not used with HTML is [an obvious untruth](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebProgramming).

Answer (score 1):

You will find guidance about all of these things on the Django website, apart from installing linux and setting up your own server box.

Please ignore that Yahoo answer.

> Django supports many different database servers and is officially supported with PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle and SQLite.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/install/#get-your-database-running